# Android ExpandedListView want SwipeToDismiss to only work on Groups

Tags: java, android

I've got what appears to be the de-facto version of SwipeToDismiss implementation from here: [google code / Roman Nurik](https://code.google.com/p/dashclock/source/browse/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/ui/SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java).

And it works great. However, I'm using it on an ExpandedListView and I would only like Groups to be dismissiable.

There appears to be two places where I can intervene and not allow the dismiss, in TouchListener event:

```
mListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // return false if not on a group ???????
    return mSwipeDismissTouchListener.onTouch(view, motionEvent);
 ..
```

or in SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener event:

```
mSwipeDismissTouchListener = new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
        mListView,
        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
            public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                // return false if not on a group ???????
            }
            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
            }
        }
);
```

But I can't work out how to tell if the click/touch event has been on a group or child.

Anyone any ideas?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adopt your adapter class an use [ViewHolder Pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) but with some modifications: make it public, make your field public, something like this

```
public static class ViewHolderGroup {
    TextView tvName;
    ImageView ivLogo;
    public boolean isGroup;
}
```

and set some variable to [Tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html), that will define wheater

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderGroup holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_group_operator, null);
        holder = new ViewHolderGroup();
        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_row_group_operator_tv_Name);
        holder.ivLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_row_group_operator_iv_Logo);
        holder.ivLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.isGroup = true;  // Here we setting field to know this is group
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
    }
   ....
 }
```

Then get this tag in code you described earlier, like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fa = this;
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_elist, container, false);

    final ExpandableListView elMain = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_fg_elist_elv_Main);
    RouteExpandableListAdapter routesAdapter = new RouteExpandableListAdapter(Rendis.mContext, Rendis.dates, Rendis.routes);
    elMain.setAdapter(routesAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(elMain);
    elMain.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    elMain.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            Rect rect = new Rect();
            int childCount = elMain.getChildCount();
            int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
            elMain.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
            int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
            int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
            View child;
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                child = elMain.getChildAt(i);
                child.getHitRect(rect);

                if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                    RouteExpandableListAdapter.ViewHolderGroup holder  = (RouteExpandableListAdapter.ViewHolderGroup) child.getTag();
                    if(holder.isGroup){
                        // DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think I've worked it out, although it feels a bit hacky:

In the adapter I add a touch listener for the getChildView and getGroupViews, this allows me to keep the type of the currently selected item.

Then in my View containing the Expanded list view in the event handlers I just ask the lists adapter if the currently touched thing is a group and if so then its ok to allow the swipe.